# How to enforce an API definition with macros or some other mechanism?

Tags: c, api, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a C header file as part of an API that I am developing which exposes a number of functions. For example:

**api.h**

```
void foo();
int bar(char * foobar);
```

Now, most functions that I expose are actually defined within the API, however, there are some that I leave to the using-developer to implement herself. To make it easier for the developer and enforce conformance to my API I added the following macros:

**api.h**(modified)

```
#define DEFINE_FOO() \
        void foo()
void foo();
#define DEFINE_BAR() \
        int bar(char * foobar)
int bar(char * foobar);
```

to be used as follows:

**implement.c**

```
#include "api.h"
DEFINE_FOO() {
    // Codez
}

DEFINE_BAR() {
    // More codez
}
```

One of the things that bothers me about this approach is that the developer will use the DEFINE_* macros but not necessarily intuit that a function, namely "bar" takes arguments. Is there a way to improve this approach or is there a better approach to enforcing custom API definitions in C? Thanks!

Comment: Use correct prototypes. Old-style declarators are deprecated. And stack overflow is not the place for discussion. (but I think your approach makes debugging harder and does not add any benefit).

Comment: It don't now use an IDE but my experience was that using macros to implement code makes it hard to trace the source code, for example line numbers don't work. I recommend to use a code macro not to apparently make life easy, but when there is no other way to do it. I don't see any problem with user supplied function `cmp` for `qsort`.

Comment: I suggest not doing this. If the user is supposed to provide some of the functions, explain it in the documentation, and show the required signatures there. The macros don't help him at all, and just make the code look unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no need to use macros and I'd recommend against it (and I've done *plenty* of "crazy" things with macros over the [last 35+] years).

If you're defining the API, this implies that you're putting [ANSI] prototypes in `api.h` for *all* your functions. That doesn't mean *you* will implement them--it only means that you define the architecture/API. Any function that doesn't have a prototype in `api.h` isn't part of the API [obviously].

If you do that, the compiler will flag any mismatches. Simply require that the developer include the `api.h` at the top.

Here's an `api.h`:

```
void foo(void);
int bar(char *foobar);
```

A well conforming `.c` will compile cleanly:

```
#include "api.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void
foo(void)
{
}

int
bar(char *str)
{
    return 0;
}
```

A non-conformant `.c` will *not* compile correctly:

```
#include "api.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void
foo(int x)
{
    printf("foo: %d\n",x);
}

int
bar(char *str)
{
    return 0;
}
```

You'll get compilation errors:

```
bad.c:5:1: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 foo(int x)
 ^
In file included from bad.c:1:0:
api.h:2:6: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 void foo(void);
      ^
```

So, if a developer makes a mistake, the ordinary code definitions will handle it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't really recommend your approach, but you can technically make it work.

You can pass arguments into macros as such:

```
#define DEFINE_BAR(arg) \
        int bar(char* arg)
```

Now the programmer can call

```
DEFINE_BAR(arg_name) {
    return strlen(arg_name);
}
```

This will be turned into the following by cpp:

```
int bar(char* arg_name) {
    return strlen(arg_name);
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend a better approach or a link describing it? Thanks

Comment: @pragmatic-penguin The better approach is just to document what the user has to implement. A macro for the first line of the definition doesn't help him at all.

Comment: I would like to echo what Barmar said. Using a macro here not only adds the confusion of debugging a macro, but documentation is necessary either way. The user will probably want to read documentation rather than inferring the necessary information from the function prototype.

However, depending on what you're actually trying to do, passing function pointers may be a better option. For example, comparators or sort functions for data structures that support sorting. Instead of forcing the user to implement your function, give them a specification and let them do what they want.